# Returning a value IEnumerator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerable

Hey guys Im new to c# and untiy I usually developed Java and have a problem returning a value using IEnumerator. Basically I have a client side script which registers a username and password to a database on a server. My problem is that when I click a button the method in the client side script should be called to add the users input for their username and password into the database. The method that is responsible for this should return a string indicating that the registration was successful/unsuccessful. When I try to implement this I get the following error :

" NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
RegisterScript.OnMouseUp () (at Assets/Scripts/RegisterScript.cs:23)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents()"

Below is the code of the two classes thanks to anyone who can help !

client side script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class ClientSideScript : MonoBehaviour {

public string RegUserUrl = "http://localhost/reguser.php?";


public IEnumerable<string> RegisterUsers(string name , string pass){

    string post_url = registerUser + "name=" + name + "&pass=" + pass;
    print (post_url);
    WWW hs_post = new WWW(post_url);
    string check = hs_post.ToString();
    yield return check;

    //return regname;
 }
 }
```

registration script attached to a button which passes the username and password to the client side script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class RegisterScript : MonoBehaviour {
public string Registeredpassword;
public string Registeredusername;
public Texture2D registerButton;



//Use this for initialization
void OnGUI () {

Registeredpassword = GUILayout.PasswordField(Registeredpassword, "*"[0], 25);
Registeredusername = GUILayout.TextField(Registeredusername, 25);

}

void OnMouseUp(){

ClientSideScript client =          (ClientSideScript)FindObjectOfType(typeof(ClientSideScript));
 IEnumerable<string> stringcheck = client.RegisterUsers(Registeredusername ,      Registeredpassword);
 print (stringcheck);
    }   
  }
```

Comment: From this upper code, I dont see anything that can be IEnumerable.

Comment: related, and with a better solution imho: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/207733/can-coroutines-return-a-value.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindObjectOfType` will return null if yout don't have an `GameObject` of that type (in your case `ClientSideScript` ) in your unity3d scene.

You will also need to change your `RegisterUsers` method to something like this

```
public IEnumerator RegisterUsers(string name , string pass){

string post_url = registerUser + "name=" + name + "&pass=" + pass;
print (post_url);
WWW hs_post = new WWW(post_url);

// wait for www to get a response
yield return hs_post;

// now do something with the returned value
// cant return it directly as this is a unity3d coroutine
string response = hs_post.text;
DealWithResponse(reponse)
```

}

It has a `IEnumerator` return type as it is needs to be a unity coroutine so the game does not wait for a response to your www call.

And when you call `RegisterUsers` from `RegisterScript` you need to use `StartCoroutine(client.RegisterUsers(name, pass));`

see Unity3d  [WWW documentation](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html) and [Coroutine documentation](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html)

Comment: Hmm? How is this answering the question? I still can't return a value with this! You're just calling a method in the end!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `FindObjectOfType` function returns a null for some reason. 
Why, it's impossible to deduct looking just on the code provided.

It's *not* `IEnumerable<string> stringcheck = client...`, but a line before (even if I don't see line numbers on text provided)

Comment: what should I use instead of IEnumberable ?

Comment: Just a string - you are always returning 1 string.

Comment: @racingWild: I repeat, this is not about Enumerable bu about your ClientSideScript object recovery (as much as can understand the code provided)

Comment: @racingWild: Looking on your stacktrace, at least on that one provided here, the last point I see is *not* RegisterUsers method, but OnMouseUp.

Comment: @JakubKonecki I tired using just a string but it gave an error saying it wasnt an iterator block.

Comment: @Tigran is their a method instead of OnMouseUp that I can use to pass data between classes ?

Comment: @racingWild: what do you mean? Just use a method of another class (if it doesn't exist, create one).

Answer (score 0):

I come across this problem too.

1.I think about put output variable in parameter list.

2.So I think about pointer,but unity 3d use safe c# which does not have pointer.

3.then I think about "ref" or "out" in c#,but a function return IEnumerator can not use "ref" or "out" in parameter list in c#.

4.Finial I think about I can write a pointer myself in safe c# with generic stuff.

Here is my solution:

```
//a pointer to another object..
public class Pointer<T>
{
    public T data;

    public Pointer(){
    }
    public Pointer(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}

  public IEnumerator RegisterUsers(string name , string pass,Pointer<string> errPtr){
    string post_url = registerUser + "name=" + name + "&pass=" + pass;
    print (post_url);
    WWW hs_post = new WWW(post_url);

    // wait for www to get a response
    yield return hs_post;

    //return it in parameter
    errPrt.data = hs_post.text;
  }
```